# Как сделать так, чтобы после отправки 3 фотографий выводилось только 1 сообщение?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Допустим пользователь отправляет 3 фотографии одним сообщением, и нужно сделать так, чтобы после 3 `json` выводилось только 1 сообщение. Мне в голове не укладывается, за что нужно зацепиться, чтобы понять - когда пришло последнее сообщение.

Когда отправляются 3 фото, то приходит 3 `json`, и вот после 3 `json` и нужно отправить сообщение пользователю, а вообще заранее неизвестно, сколько отправится фото, может 2, а может и 5. Я написал небольшой код, но в моем случае он либо выведет 3 сообщения `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Описание')` либо не выведет ничего, если поставить в моем коде `return`. Нужно примерно похожее на `message[-1]`, но это не работает. Подскажите, как такое реализовать?

Пример кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo', 'video'])  
def second(message):    
    specification = message.text
    if message.media_group_id:
        idphoto = message.photo[0].file_id
        conn, cursor = connecting()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO orders VALUES (?,?)", (message.chat.id, idphoto))
        conn.commit()
        #return # либо будет выводить 3 сообщения ниже, либо ни одного
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Описание')
```

Comment: если сообщений определенное количество, то как вариант - сделать счётчик, по которому он будет понимать, что надо слать ответ

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, окей, если я сделаю счетчик - как мне в условии узнать, что `message` оказался последним?

Comment: ну говорю же. если фиксированное (только 3), то прокатит. считаешь, сколько тебе пришло и когда счётчик = 3 посылаешь сообщение

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov, уже подправил, что значение не фиксированное. Может быть и 2 фото, может быть и 5 фото. Но я полагаю, если фотографий можно отправить только 10 за 1 раз, то можно придумать что-то со счетчиком.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если говорить об `aiogram`, то есть гораздо лучшее и элегантное решение, как отправить **только** 1 сообщение, если приходят 2 и больше изображений (до 10) от пользователя за один раз.

Во-первых: не нужно будет создавать лишнее хранилище - `fsm` от `aiogram` и так уже его предоставляет

Во-вторых: не нужно делать проверку по `media_group_id`, для каждого юзера выделяется собственный словарь, куда можно записать идентификаторы изображений. Итого, пример кода:

```
class MyState(StatesGroup):
    brand = State()
    model = State()


async def start_state(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Прикрепите до 10 изображений")
    await MyState.brand.set()


@dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentType.PHOTO, state=MyState.brand)
async def my_brand(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if not await state.get_data():
        await state.update_data(photo=[message.photo[-1].file_id])
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Укажите название")
        await MyState.model.set()
    else:
        my_list = await state.get_data()
        photos = my_list.get("photo")
        photos.append(message.photo[-1].file_id)
        await state.update_data(photo=photos)


@dp.message_handler(state=MyState.model)
async def my_model(message, state: FSMContext):
    print(await state.get_data()) # вот здесь и будут находиться все фото
    # которые отправил юзер
    await state.finish()
```

Answer (score 1):

Описанный случай - отправка медиагруппы.
Сколько тебе прилетит сообщений, ты не знаешь, поэтому ответам в комментариях не верь.

В объекте [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) есть идентификатор `media_group_id`, который совпадает у сообщений из одной группы.

Создай временное хранилище, например `set()`.

В обработчик добавь логику:

1. Если уже отвечал на сообщение с таким идентификатором - ничего не делаешь.
2. Если ещё не отвечал - добавь идентификатор в хранилище.

Таким образом ответ улетит только `1` раз при получении нескольких сообщений из одной группы.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, сейчас попробую подобное реализовать, и чуть позже отпишу)

Comment: Можно было бы посмотреть на небольшой примерчик от вас:)? Вместо хранилища я заменю на базу sqlite (не хочу создавать глобальных хранилищ в боте, кроме самой бд, ну или словаря по идентификатору чата). Но вот проблема - пользователь отправляет, допустим, 4 фото, и я создаю sql-запрос - добавляю идентификатор `media_group_id` в базу, а как дальше действовать пока не понимаю.

Comment: Ааа, дошло уже) Если такой идентификатор в базе существует - то не отправлять больше сообщения, гениально. А вы, кстати, предлагали создать глобальное множество с помощью `set()` или как-то реализовать его локально в функции?

Comment: Можно и глобально, для одного случая он нужен на 1 секунду. Можно отправить сообщение, а через 2 секунды удалить идентификатор из сета, чтобы место не занимал. 
Обычно для таких "костылей" используют локальный или внешний кэш, но не базу данных.

Comment: Вопрос - а если ботом пользуется большое количество людей, и например, в один момент у одного пользователя создается множество, а у другого в этот же момент - удаляется, может ли это вызвать какие-то ошибки? Ранее просто не использовал множества в своих проектах.

Comment: set надо создать 1 раз, потом добавлять элементы и удалять элементы. Это не вызовет конфликтов. Проверял такую систему на боте-милионнике, пока не перешёл на внешнее хранилище.